# Protractor get scale or scaled width and height of an element

Tags: javascript, css, protractor

I'm having a bit of a problem with protractor. I actually need the width and height of an element. On the element a transform will be done and a scale will be set.

I actually need the scaled width and height of that element using protractor.

I already have the width and height using the getSize() function but the returned value is the original width and height and not the scaled width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`:

```
protractor.promise.all([
    elm.getAttribute("clientWidth"), 
    elm.getAttribute("clientHeight")
]).then(function (dimensions) {
    console.log(dimensions);
});
```

`elm.getCssValue("width")` and `elm.getCssValue("height")` are another alternatives.

Also see:

- [getSize().height vs getAttribute("clientHeight") vs getCssValue("height")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541895/getsize-height-vs-getattributeclientheight-vs-getcssvalueheight)